# Отключить разбиение на чанки Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack4, requirejs

Проект на `Backbone.js + RequireJs` собирается с помощью `webpack`, содержимое `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'js', 'core', 'main.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'themes', 'admin', 'assets', 'js', 'dist'),
        filename: 'admin.min.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

После выполнения команды `webpack --watch --mode=development`, создаются файлы:

```
0.admin.min.js
1.admin.min.js
2.admin.min.js
3.admin.min.js
admin.min.js
```

Можно сделать, чтобы всё собиралось только в 1 файл `admin.min.js`?

Comment: Это весь конфиг?

Comment: Создаются все сразу или создаётся новый после каждого изменения ?

Comment: @bonusrk, да весь

Comment: Создаются все сразу

Comment: попробуй ```optimization: {
    splitChunks: false}``` . Но как то там много отдано на дефолтные настройки. Даже `rules` делают...ничего.

Comment: @bonusrk, спасибо, сработало)

Comment: Еще бы) я еще это же и ответом могу =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За разбиение на чанки в 4й версии Webpack отвечает не плагин (как это было ранее), а опция в конфигурации.

Там большое количество различных настроек, но если необходимо просто отключить:

```
optimization: { splitChunks: false}
```

Все настройки:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks